# How can I get PnpDeviceId of Antecedent and Dependent device using get-wmiobject in single output?

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I want to get PnpDeviceId of Antecedent and  Dependent device using get-wmiobject -class Win32_SCSIControllerDevice in single output (for example in a table).
I figure it out that I can do:

```
 Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SCSIControllerDevice | ForEach-Object { [WMI]$_.Antecedent}  | Format-Table PnpDeviceId
```

and

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SCSIControllerDevice | ForEach-Object { [WMI]$_.Dependent}  | Format-Table PnpDeviceId
```

How can I nest those two commands to get result like example bellow?

```
PnpDeviceId                 PnpDeviceId
-----------                 -----------
PnpDeviceIdAntecedentDevice PnpDeviceIdDependentDevice
PnpDeviceIdAntecedentDevice PnpDeviceIdDependentDevice
PnpDeviceIdAntecedentDevice PnpDeviceIdDependentDevice
```

EDIT:

Using

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SCSIControllerDevice | ForEach-Object { [WMI]$_.Antecedent, [WMI]$_.Dependent } | Format-Table PnpDeviceId
```

I got:

```
PnpDeviceId               
-----------                 
PnpDeviceIdAntecedentDevice
PnpDeviceIdDependentDevice
PnpDeviceIdAntecedentDevice 
PnpDeviceIdDependentDevice
PnpDeviceIdAntecedentDevice 
PnpDeviceIdDependentDevice
```

I experiment with different formats but there are not in signle line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the properties using the [Select-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) (alias `select`) cmdlet:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SCSIControllerDevice | select Antecedent, Dependent
```

**Edit:**

If you want to select a nested property, you can use a custom select statement:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SCSIControllerDevice | Select @{e={([WMI]$_.Antecedent).PNPDeviceID}; l='Antecedent PNPDeviceID'}, @{e={([WMI]$_.Dependent).PNPDeviceID}; l='Dependent PNPDeviceID'}
```

**Output:**

```
Antecedent PNPDeviceID                                       Dependent PNPDeviceID                                           
----------------------                                       ---------------------                                           
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_282A&SUBSYS_05351028&REV_04\3&11583659&0&FA SCSI\DISK&VEN_LITEONIT&PROD_LCT-256M3S\4&62C5D10&0&000000       
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_282A&SUBSYS_05351028&REV_04\3&11583659&0&FA SCSI\CDROM&VEN_TSSTCORP&PROD_DVD-ROM_TS-U333B\4&62C5D10&0&010000
```

Comment: This selects whole path and I need only what is after DeviceId. I know I can parse it later but i am looking for way that i have nice and clean output

Comment: Okay, I added a custom select example.